# Trying to use a GridBagLayout to manage JPanels in Java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am currently making my first steps with GUIs and am right now just trying to make a `JFrame` with two `JPanel` containers according to my work of art here:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wq1f.png]

I chose the `GridBagLayout` since I want it to be resizeable later but keep the given proportions, yet I'm having a hard time understanding how all of this works.

My current code looks like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

     private JPanel contentPane;
         
    public JPanel getContentPane() {
        return contentPane;
    }

    public void setContentPane(JPanel contentPane) {
        this.contentPane = contentPane;
    }

    public MyFrame (){

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridheight = 3;
        JPanel blue = new JPanel();
        blue.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        contentPane.add(blue, gbc);


        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 3;
        JPanel gruen = new JPanel();
        gruen.setBackground(Color.green);
        contentPane.add(gruen, gbc);

        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(630, 650));
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setContentPane(contentPane);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyFrame();
    }
}
```

Which gives me this empty window:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmIo5.png]

If someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong that would be great.

Comment: Plus points for using `GridBagLayout` - a lot of Java people won't touch it
Minus points for posting code as images. Please never post images of text. They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.

Please post the actual code as text

Comment: You should have prompted me - didn't see you'd edited

Comment: I received help and i was told what i did wrong. Am i supposed to share the solution or delete the question since it is still closed?

Comment: Not sure if you can. Also not sure why it was closed since you did the right thing and reposted the code properly

Comment: @g00se The question is open now. **OP:** Please share the solution. Then (after a time) you can click the 'tick' box to show it is the solution (or at least the solution accepted by you!). That helps people find solutions later & is the thing to do here. Glad you got it sorted. :)

Comment: That's good but too late for what I was going to post by the looks ;) @yebanko - did you go to another site for your advice?

Comment: Kind of. Just sent the closed question to @dmoebius and got an private answer. And it was pretty much what was explained very well in detail in the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. First of all, you need to remove this:**

```java
public JPanel getContentPane() {
    return contentPane;
}

public void setContentPane(JPanel contentPane) {
    this.contentPane = contentPane;
}
```

because you basically override the base logic of `JFrame`, hence you may (and likely will) break something.

**2. The second thing is** that putting component to the grid cells with constraints does not automatically stretch them across the area. If to refer to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), you will see that:

> Essentially, GridBagLayout places components in rectangles (cells) in a grid, and then uses the components' preferred sizes to determine how big the cells should be.

**3. Automatic stretching** can be achieved with `fill` property of constraints. But you still need to declare the required sizes somehow.

**4. The sizes** specification can be set up with `weightx` and `weighty` properties of constraints.

> Weights are used to determine how to distribute space among columns (weightx) and among rows (weighty); this is important for specifying resizing behavior.

So in your simple case you basically have two columns where one have `0.7` of x weight and another have `0.3`.

The below code demonstrates the complete solution:

```java
class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    public MyFrame (){
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 0.2/0.3;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        JPanel blue = new JPanel();
        blue.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        contentPane.add(blue, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 0.1/0.3;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        JPanel green = new JPanel();
        green.setBackground(Color.green);
        contentPane.add(green, gbc);

        setContentPane(contentPane);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(630, 650));
        pack();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyFrame();
    }
}
```

[image]